# Is there any difference between module.exports and module.export in solidity?

Tags: javascript, node.js, web3js, truffle

Was facing an issue while trying to use truffle migrate on this code:

```
const Migrations = artifacts.require("Migrations");

module.exports = function(deployer) {
  deployer.deploy(Migrations);
};
```

The fix to it was changing from **module.exports** to **module.export** and using **truffle migrate --reset**. So the code which worked was

```
const Migrations = artifacts.require("Migrations");

module.export = function(deployer) {
  deployer.deploy(Migrations);
};
```

So the question still remains, What is the difference between module.exports and module.export

Comment: This question should have the tag `javascript` (ore `nodejs`), not `solidity`, as `module.export` is something related to how modules are handled within NodeJs, not in Solidity

Answer (score 0):

actually these lines of code is not solidity and it's JavaScript, however when you use export in fact you export just 1 item from file but when you use exports in fact you just export and object and one of the keys of this object is assign to your function.
so the difference is when you want import your method from another file like code blocks below.

```
const item = () => {}    
module.export = item
// where you want import it you have to user somthing like this
const item = require('path of your file')
```

while when you use exports, actually you export and object from your file.

```
const item = () => {}    
module.exports = item
// where you want import it you have to user something like this
const { item } = require('path of your file')
```

but in your case just use exports because I have experience on this and it will do your job

Comment: Could you explain a bit more about 'export and object?

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_objects.asp

Comment: if you read about object from link below. each time you use exports you export and object instead if you use export you just export a single data or function or anything else you working with.